# PHP insert Unknown number of rows in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach, pdo

I am doing a script where it is possible to write name and age for people to register them in a list.

```
  <p>
    1.
    <input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" >
    <input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" >
    <input name="age" type="text" id="age" >
  </p>
  <p>
    2.
    <input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" >
    <input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" >
    <input name="age" type="text" id="age" >
  </p>
  <p>
    3.
    <input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" >
    <input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" >
    <input name="age" type="text" id="age" >
  </p>
etc.
```

And I am having a jQuery script that appends an extra line if needed.

Then I was wondering how to do when I need my PHP script to import the data. It is easy to manage individual fields, but since there is a list of the same names, I must use some kind of foreach statement. I am writing in PDO, so  would prefer answers related to PDO and not mysql queries.

```
  <p>
    <!-- added with jQuery -->
    4.
    <input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" >
    <input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" >
    <input name="age" type="text" id="age" >
  </p>
```

Comment: The names should differ in each line, because when it will serialize you will get only one the first attribute set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to read them in like that in PHP unless you use `[]` at the end of the name to indicate it's an array.

If you do that something like this should work:

```
foreach( $_POST['first_name'] AS $num=>$first_name ){
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'][$num];
    $age = $_POST['age'][$num];
    // Do your insert here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set same names for all same type inputs (`first_name[]`, `last_name[]`, `age[]`) so you get arrays when you post form data, and than in PHP you can go foreach and insert new row

Comment: To be honest, I have never worked with arrays before.. Could you show me an example please?

Comment: Suresh Kamrushi's answer is good example of html structure, and scragar is for PHP script :)

Comment: Here you can read about arrays http://no.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php. This html form allows php to read directly the various values from the global variables

Answer (score 2):

You should build html like this-

```
<input name="first_name[]" type="text" id="first_name" >
<input name="last_name[]" type="text" id="last_name" >
<input name="age[]" type="text" id="age" >
```

Than you can access your values -

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
```